# Android using SwipeRefreshLayout animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, swiperefreshlayout

Is it possible to use only SwipeRefreshLayout loading animation without really refreshing view i.e on initial loading lot's of data?

**This animation:**

[image]

I want to show swipe animation before any view is show, as preloader for view.

Tried different combinations on wiew create, when I use

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

and

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

Thing works fine, but my swipe listener then doesn't work, it doesn't even catches event.

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                SomeCustomFragment.refreshFragment();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
```

**Is that I'm trying to do even possible?**

Comment: You can use an indeterminate progress bar.

Comment: I wouldn't do that, as it is not clear to the user what happened. The animation indicates he swiped, but he didn't. For updates that happen because the app does something by itself, I'd always use an update indicator in the toolbar of the activity or a progress dialog.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yeah, I'm already using it, but I got suggestion that this way loading animation would be more effective, so I'm trying to implement it this way

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I'm already doing that but as I mentioned I got suggestion that this way loading would be more effective from UX point of view so I tried to see how it would look like. 

So for you this is not the way of doing things?

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way, no. I'd leave that animation for a swipe refresh only.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I think I'll go that way and leave it as it is. Tnx for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
refreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                // load data
                .....
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code to trigger the swipe refresh layout programmatically.

```
 swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        }
    });
```

By calling directly `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true)` the `OnRefreshListener` will NOT get executed.

In order to stop the circular loading animation call `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Views will be rendered on the screen after the onCreate() method. So you need to have a callback function that executes after the onCreate() method.
Something like below will do the trick.

```
swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                //Do your stuff here
        }
});
```

Remember to set the animation off by setting

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)
```

As soon as you're done with the task